# Яндекс карты. Путевые точки

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Как скрыть(не удалить) путевые точки и линию маршрута?

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, подробнее зачем вам это нужно? Возможно то что вы хотите реализовать можно сделать как-то по-другому.

Comment: Я реализую карту с расчетом стоимости доставки товара. То, что находится внутри кад - бесплатно,  за кад - считаем километры. В первом варианте было достаточно примера из [песочницы](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/deliveryCalculator) с некоторыми доработками. Теперь же нужно скрыть путевые точки(**A** и **B**) и линию маршрута. А на адрес доставки повесить баллун с количеством километров и стоимостью.  По моей логике, можно скрыть точки с маршрутом и в конечной точке вывести стоимость.

Answer (score 1):

Маршрут не обязательно добавлять на карту. [Информацию о маршруте получаешь програмно](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/router/multiRouter-docpage/#multiRouter__route-get-info). `console.log` замени на добавление балуна. [фидл: длинна есть, маршрута нет](https://jsfiddle.net/xcL5twa3/)

```
ymaps.ready(function () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
            zoom: 9
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        });




    var multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
    referencePoints: [
      'метро Парк Культуры',
      'метро Арбатская'
    ]
});

multiRoute.model.events.add('requestsuccess', function() {
    // Получение ссылки на активный маршрут.
    var activeRoute = multiRoute.getActiveRoute();
    // Вывод информации о маршруте.
    console.log("Длина: " + activeRoute.properties.get("distance").text);
    console.log("Время прохождения: " + activeRoute.properties.get("duration").text);
    });

});
```

Comment: Следует заметить, что не отображение на карте полученных и используемых данных нарушает третье условие бесплатного использования API Яндекс.Карт, а потому пригодно только при наличии коммерческой лицензии. https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index.html